# How Can I Hide Or Mitigate Sourcemap Parsing Warnings In DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, warnings, source-maps

Chrome has started showing me (a lot of) warnings for missing sourcemaps. The warnings take the following format:

> DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: webpack://AdminFrontend/Users/me/Sites/example/node_modules/@sentry/utils/esm/instrument.js.map

I can click 'Selected context only' in Devtools > console and the warnings disappear, however this checkbox is not sticky so I need to do this every time.

I am using within my Webpack config:

```
 new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
    filename: '[name].map',
 }),
```

*Note that the sourcemap for the app itself is successfully generated and parsed, and no warning is issued for it. This question specifically relates to the warnings about third-party libs in the `/node_modules/` directory.*

**How can I permanently hide these warnings, or remove them through my build config?**

Comment: While not a proper solution, adding `-SourceMap` as a filter helped me. See https://superuser.com/a/1028554